# I want to use image_tag for the [ number set ] not just one number. (Ruby)

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

It is kind of lottery, when you press F5 , new balls come out in the site.
My goal is to show the organized number balls in Ascending order.
(and I use Cloud9)
of course I have numbered photos like ***1.jpg*** , ***2.jpg*** ...
and add them in the folder of C9 (Cloud9)

there are two solution I think

1. I want to re-organized the "sampled number"
2. image tag to listed number set

This is my trial

```
    @todaynum= @allnum.sample
    @todaynum1= @allnum.sample
    @todaynum2= @allnum.sample
    @todaynum3= @allnum.sample
    @todaynum4= @allnum.sample
    @todaynum5= @allnum.sample 

    @numimg= @todaynum+".jpg"
    @numimg1= @todaynum1+".jpg"
    @numimg2= @todaynum2+".jpg"
    @numimg3= @todaynum3+".jpg"
    @numimg4= @todaynum4+".jpg"
    @numimg5= @todaynum5+".jpg"

    arr = (@todaynum,@todaynum1,@todaynum2,@todaynum3,@todaynum4,@todaynum5)
    arr.sort!

    puts arr $array = Array.new(45)
    $array = (1..45).to_a
    @lotto_list = $array.sample(6).sort
    @lotto_list_image = $array.sample(6).sort ".jpg"
```

**html.erb file**

```
<%=@lotto_list%>
<%=image_tag lotto_list_image %>
```

but, it doesn't work at all ..

or

```
lotto list image = ~~ something(I don't know..) ~~ ".jpg"I want to do like this.
```

It is so hard for me to go over this problem...
How should I do?

This is my code

```
class numbersetController < ApplicationController
  def numbers
    @allnum=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45"]

    @todaynum= @allnum.sample
    @todaynum1= @allnum.sample
    @todaynum2= @allnum.sample
    @todaynum3= @allnum.sample
    @todaynum4= @allnum.sample
    @todaynum5= @allnum.sample 

    @numimg= @todaynum+".jpg"
    @numimg1= @todaynum1+".jpg"
    @numimg2= @todaynum2+".jpg"
    @numimg3= @todaynum3+".jpg"
    @numimg4= @todaynum4+".jpg"
    @numimg5= @todaynum5+".jpg"

    arr = (@todaynum,@todaynum1,@todaynum2,@todaynum3,@todaynum4,@todaynum5)
    arr.sort!
    puts arr

    $array = Array.new(45)
    $array = (1..45).to_a

    @lotto_list = $array.sample(6).sort

  end
end
```

**html.erb file**

```
<h1>lotto balls newbie.version</h1>

<p><%=image_tag @numimg%></p> 
<h2><%=image_tag @numimg1%></h2>
<h3><%=image_tag @numimg2%></h3>
<h4><%=image_tag @numimg3%></h4>
<h5><%=image_tag @numimg4%></h5>
<h6><%=image_tag @numimg5%></h6>

<%=@todaynum%>  
<%=@todaynum1%>
<%=@todaynum2%>
<%=@todaynum3%>
<%=@todaynum4%>
<%=@todaynum5%>

<h1> ruby random number (for test) </h1>
<%=@lotto_list%>
```

Comment: Why don't just loop over array and use some meta

Comment: Put the name of the files: `numberset_controller.rb`, `sampled.html.erb`, ... That will make more easy to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track on the second try you did, just need a second call to `map` to format it the way you want it.

```
# note: probably want to rename the controller like so
class NumbersetController < ApplicationController
  def numbers
    @lotto_ball_images = *(1..45).to_a.sample(6).sort.map(&:to_s).map{|n| "lotto-ball-image-number#{n}.jpg"}
  end
end
```

then something like this in the template.

```
<h1>lotto balls </h1>

<% @lotto_ball_images.each do |src| %>
   <%= image_tag(src) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: (changed order of map to make sure it sorted in numeric format instead of alpha)

Comment: amazing.. I'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: HI @JHK, if this does work for you, if you could click the check mark to accept the answer I would be obliged.

Comment: actually now that I look at it you can skip the .map(&:to_s) part entirely. 
`@lotto_ball_images  = *(1..45).to_a.sample(6).sort.map{|n| "lotto-ball-image-number#{n}.jpg"}`